# for jdk17/springboot3.2.2 - what maven dependency would contain package: org.springframework.scheduling.commonj?

Tags: java-17, spring-boot-3

I'm upgrading an existing app

from:

jdk11/springboot2.7

to:

jdk17/springboot3.2.2

QUESTION: what maven dependency would contain package:  org.springframework.scheduling.commonj?

as in...

import org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.TimerManagerTaskScheduler;

import org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor;

I've tried adding either:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

or,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

but, with no success... --i.e.,  the maven build/compile continues to complain:  "package org.springframework.scheduling.commonj does not exist"

(presuming it's possibly deprecated - if so, what can I easily replace it with?)

thx for any help (near zero hits on this topic when "googling")

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of [WorkManagerTaskExecutor](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-context-support/5.3.12/org/springframework/scheduling/commonj/WorkManagerTaskExecutor.html) its was deprecated and the recommendation it to use `DefaultManagedTaskExecutor`

> as of 5.1, in favor of the EE 7/8 based
> org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.DefaultManagedTaskExecutor

[Similarly](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-context-support/5.3.12/org/springframework/scheduling/commonj/TimerManagerTaskScheduler.html) for `TimerManagerTaskScheduler` its too to use `DefaultManagedTaskScheduler`